# setListAdapter() not working

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, contacts

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Uri allContacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
            Cursor c = managedQuery(allContacts, null, null, null, null);
            String[] columns = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID};
            int[] views = new int[] {R.id.contactName, R.id.contactID};
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_main, c, columns,views);    
            this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

it always shows this error :The method setListAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter) is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: u need to extend ListActivity for setListAdapter..

Answer (score 4):

In order to use `setListAdapter` your class has to extends `ListActivity` not `Activity`. Change

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

with

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

After change extends Activity with extends ListActivity, If the problem is not over, you can try to 
Change :

`import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;`

with:

`import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;`